# Xcode set constraints relative to side of screen instead of another component

Tags: ios, xcode, nslayoutconstraint, size-classes

How can I set a component to have a constraint that is relative to the side of the screen rather than another component?  I've heard that I can use size classes to do this, but I can't find how to use size classes to just set a components offset relative to the side of the screen.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0):

Just place leading and trailing constraints to the main view of your vie controller from the desired component.

To do this, in the interface builder select your component and just control drag to the main view and select leading and trailing constraints.